# Can I access CLI programs from within Node's child_process?

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process

I’ve written a node script that `cd`’s into multiple directories in sequence and executes bash commands in order to deploy the contents of the repos to my development environment.

Native bash commands work fine, like `cd`, `ls`, but it looks like the subshell or child process (or whatever the proper term is, I don’t understand the inner workings of Bash) that’s opened by node doesn’t have anything available to my normal prompt.

E.g.

- the custom bash toolset that’s available globally
- `nvm` (is this even possible, to run a different version of node within a node subshell?)
- gulp breaks because it doesn't have the necessary node version installed.

Is it possible to access these programs/commands from the node subshell? I’m using the `child_process` node module.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function command (command) {
    exec (command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            error(err);
        } else {
            message(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            message(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        }
    });
}
```

Used as in:

```
command('nvm use 6');
command('gulp build');
command('pde deploy');
```

Comment: Found the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725871/nodejs-child-process-exec-command-failed-with-nvm-permission-denied-osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child process is not run as `bash`. child_process spawns the executable using the regular `sh` shell.
If you need the commands to run within `bash`, the command line you run needs to be wrapped in `bash -c`. For example:

```
command('bash -c "my command here"');
```

Also, each command you run is a sub-process, which does not affect the parent process, nor any subsequent sub processes. Thus, a shell built-in like `cd` will only change the directory for that sub-process, which immediately goes away. You will see this if you run:

```
command('cd /');
command('ls');
```

The `ls` command will show the current working directory, not the root directory.

If you run your command with `bash -c` and the `$PATH` and other environment variables still aren't set up the way you need them, you need to debug your shell start-up scripts. Perhaps there's a difference between interactive shells (`.bash_profile`) and all shells (`.bashrc`).

Note that fully non-interactive shells may need to explicitly have the start-up script you want to run specified.